# Speed up slow loading website on mobile due to 3rd party analytics scripts

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile, google-analytics, amp-html

Speed tests report that my site loads in about [8 seconds](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/disputebills.com/VugpFdyF) on mobile and [2 on desktop](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/disputebills.com/Ll9W07Tx).

When looking at the "waterfall" of the asset/script loading it seems to be mostly due to 3rd party analytic scripts like zendesk, hubspot, and google analytics.

Is there anyway to optimize a site for mobile when using these type of scripts?

As far as the files go on my site I've optimized them nearly as much as I could. I've even used a cron (probably not a great idea) to cache the google analytics script locally and fetch a newer version every few days.

I've looked into using Tag Manager or something like [Segment](https://segment.com/) to optimize the script loading of these files, but I'm not sure if that will actually improve performance or if those services are mostly just for convenience.

I've also looked at [service workers](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/service-worker) for mobile app caching, but I'm not sure if that will help either and don't want to dive into learning how to use them if it won't actually make a difference.

To sum up, is there a way to speed up mobile with multiple 3rd party analytic scripts or am I just going to have to forgo using some of them or possibly add a mobile version or [AMP version](https://www.ampproject.org/) without using them or some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged AMP in your question, I'll answer from the AMP perspective:

AMP solves this problem by using a **mediator that connects directly to the endpoints of various analytics providers**, replacing their clunky and power hungry JS scripts.

Of course, AMP comes with its own set of constrains and is really only targeted at powering static content, but if you're willing to go that route, learn more about [AMP Analytics here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/analytics_amp.html).